# A completely wrong answer "looks ok"

Tags: feature-request, review

Normally when we review low quality post, some wrong answer will show up (I guess that's because someone has flagged it as "very low quality"?). And I am a bit unsure what to do.

Obviously I will not choose to recommend deletion: even a wrong answer can do good to some others anyway.

Also that is nothing for me to edit. The format is fine.

So I can choose only "looks OK". But the answer just don't look ok. Can we change that option to "No action needed" for example?

Comment: IIIRC it even used to be "Looks good." To me "Looks OK" is fine; it  might not be good but it is good enough not to delete it, so it is OK as a post.

Comment: @quid: So might be it is just a cultural difference. In my usage (I am from Hong Kong) "OK" is quite closed to "good".

Comment: Possibly. I am not best placed to comment on this but indeed I am under the impression that in a US context, which is likely most relevant here, somebody responding "It was OK." on a question how they liked something, e.g. a restaurant, rather intends to express that it was acceptable but there were also disappointing aspects.

Comment: For most of these buttons there is a tooltip, which explains a bit more about the intended use of that button. But I have no review available now so I can't check.

Comment: The tooltip of "Looks OK" for a question is "this question doesn't seem low-quality". When one clicks "(more)" the help text is "Looks OK: if nothing is wrong with this question". I don't have a review available for an answer so I can't say, but I guess it's similar.

Comment: @Najib Actually then, the tooltip is quite fine (using "seem"). The help text is wrong (it should also use "seems"). If that is fixed, we can say that "Looks OK" and "Is OK" are related but different things.